# Signal with side effects derived from another signal, multiple subscribers

Tags: reactive-cocoa

OK, this one has got me a bit stumped.

I have a two-step login process that I'm trying to model using ReactiveCocoa and provide a signal that lets subscribers know if a client is authenticated.

The two step process is:

1. Obtain a session token
2. Verify the session token works by calling an API endpoint

I'll try and simplify things, but I have an object, lets call it `UserSession`, which has a simple property `isLoggedIn`, which returns YES if the user has a session token and NO if it doesn't. This value changes and emits the usual KVO notifications when the session token is fetched and set on the `UserSession` object. I can observe this property using `RACObserve` if I just want to know when I have a token.

What I really want to do is have a property on `UserSession` called `authenticated` which returns an `RACSignal`. This signal should:

- Emit NO if isLoggedIn changes to NO
- Emit YES if isLoggedIn changes to YES and the verification request is successful
- Emit NO if isLoggedIn changes to YES and the verification request fails.

A simple, naive implementation looks like this:

```
- (RACSignal *)authenticated
{
  if (_authenticated == nil) {
    _authenticated = [RACObserve(self, isLoggedIn) flattenMap:^id(NSNumber *isLoggedIn) {
      if (isLoggedIn.boolValue) {
        // does the async HTTP request, wrapped up in a signal that emits YES/NO, or error
        // then completes.
        return [self verifySessionToken];
      }
      return [RACSignal return:@NO];
    }];
  }
  return _authenticated;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that a verification request will be fired for every subscriber - I only want one verification request to be sent for a single change in the `isLoggedIn` property.

I've tried to use a multicast connection, wrapping `[self doVerificationRequest]` in a `defer` block, multicasting it and then returning the multicast signal inside the `flattenMap` block. This sort of works - it prevents multiple verification requests - but subsequent changes to the `isLoggedIn` property do not trigger a new verification request.

To be clear, the following sequence works as expected:

1. No session token, `isLoggedIn` starts as `NO`
2. `authenticated` emits `NO`
3. User logs in, gets a session token
4. `isLoggedIn` changes to `YES`, triggers a verification request
5. Verification request is successful, `authenticated` emits `YES`

The following sequence does not work:

1. Expired session token present, `isLoggedIn` starts as `YES`
2. Verification request triggered, it fails
3. `authenticated` emits `NO`
4. Login screen presented in response to this, user logs in, gets new session token
5. `isLoggedIn` should emit another `YES` to its `RACObserve` and trigger another verification request, but this never happens.

Is there a way to achieve what I want here?

Edit: this was my multicast attempt:

```
- (RACSignal *)authenticated
{
    if (_authenticated == nil) {
        RACSignal *deferredVerification = [RACSignal defer:^RACSignal *{
            return [self verifySessionToken];
        }];

        self.tokenVerificationConnection = [deferredVerification publish];

        _authenticated = [RACObserve(self, isLoggedIn) flattenMap:^id(NSNumber *isLoggedIn) {
            if (isLoggedIn.boolValue) {
                return [self.tokenVerificationConnection autoconnect];
            }
            return [RACSignal return:@NO];
        }];
    }
    return _authenticated;
}
```

This also appears to behave mostly the same way with less code but the same behaviour as above. I've added the do blocks to try and visualise what is happening:

```
- (RACSignal *)authenticated
{
    if (_authenticated == nil) {
        @weakify(self);

        _authenticated = [[[[RACObserve(self, isLoggedIn) doNext:^(id x) {
            NSLog(@"LOGGED IN %@", x);
        }] flattenMap:^id(NSNumber *isLoggedIn) {
            @strongify(self);

            if (isLoggedIn.boolValue) {
                return [self verifySessionToken];
            }
            return [RACSignal return:@NO];
        }] doNext:^(id x) {
            NSLog(@"AUTH: %@", x);
        }] replay];
    }
    return _authenticated;
}
```

In scenario 2 above, I never see the LOGGED IN or AUTH log calls when the session token is set after logging in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it looks like I found my own answer. I wasn't far off with either of my multicast/replay solutions. The problem was that the signal returned by `[self verifySessionToken]` would send an error if the connection failed in some way, which was breaking the whole thing.

I could have fixed this by having it send @NO instead of an error but I decided to leave it as it is and make the error handling explicit.

I also found using replay on the outer signal to be more elegant than using the multicast on the inner signal.

This was my final working solution:

```
- (RACSignal *)authenticated
{
    if (_authenticated == nil) {
        @weakify(self);

        _authenticated = [[RACObserve(self, isLoggedIn) flattenMap:^id(NSNumber *isLoggedIn) {
            @strongify(self);

            if (isLoggedIn.boolValue) {
                return [[self verifySessionToken] catch:^RACSignal *(NSError *error) {
                    DDLogError(@"Error verifying session token");
                    return [RACSignal return:@NO];
                }];
            }
            return [RACSignal return:@NO];
        }] replay];
    }
    return _authenticated;
}
```